Django LoginRequiredMixin not redirecting to login page
I have a django e-commerce website and when I am trying to add a product without logging in, I am not being redirected to the login page.
When I try to add a product without being logged in, on my terminal it says:
 [16/Jun/2024 07:18:26] "POST /cart/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[16/Jun/2024 07:18:26] "GET /login/?next=/cart/ HTTP/1.1" 200 134934
But I stay on the same page. Why is this not redirecting me to the login page? Thanks in advance!
My views.py:
def user_login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        CustomUser = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if CustomUser is not None:
            login(request, CustomUser)
            messages.success(request, 'Login successful.')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password.')

    return render(request, 'users/user_login.html')

class CartView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request):
        cart_items = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        total_price = sum(item.product.price * item.quantity for item in cart_items)
        return render(request, 'business/cart.html', {'cart_items': cart_items, 'total_price': total_price})

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            product_id = data.get('product_id')
            selected_variations = data.get('selected_variations', [])
            quantity = data.get('quantity', 1)  # Get the quantity from the request
            logger.debug(f'Received product_id: {product_id} with variations: {selected_variations} with quantity {quantity}')
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            logger.error("Invalid JSON data in the request body")
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid JSON data'}, status=400)

        if not product_id:
            logger.error("No product_id provided in the request")
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'No product_id provided'}, status=400)

        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)

        variation_categories = product.variations.count()

        if product.has_variations and len(selected_variations) != variation_categories:
            messages.error(request, f"Please select all {variation_categories} variations.")
            return JsonResponse({'error': f'Please select all {variation_categories} variations.'}, status=400)

        variation_key = "-".join(sorted(str(v_id) for v_id in selected_variations))

        cart_item = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user, product=product, variation_key=variation_key).first()

        if cart_item:
            cart_item.quantity += quantity
        else:
            cart_item = Cart.objects.create(
                user=request.user,
                product=product,
                quantity=quantity,  # Set the quantity
                variation_key=variation_key
            )
            for variation_id in selected_variations:
                product_variation = get_object_or_404(ProductVariation, id=variation_id)
                CartItemVariation.objects.create(cart=cart_item, product_variation=product_variation)

        cart_item.save()

        cart_items = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        cart_data = []
        for item in cart_items:
            item_variations = [v.product_variation.value for v in item.variations.all()]
            cart_data.append({
                'id': item.id,
                'product': {
                    'id': item.product.id,
                    'name': item.product.name,
                    'price': float(item.product.price),
                    'image': item.product.image.url if item.product.image else None,
                },
                'variations': item_variations,
                'quantity': item.quantity,
            })
        total_price = sum(item.product.price * item.quantity for item in cart_items)

        logger.debug("Returning updated cart data as JSON response")
        return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'items': cart_data, 'subtotal': total_price})

    def get_cart_data(self, request):
        logger.debug("Received request to fetch cart data")
        cart_items = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        cart_data = []
        for item in cart_items:
            item_variations = [v.product_variation.value for v in item.variations.all()]
            cart_data.append({
                'id': item.id,
                'product': {
                    'id': item.product.id,
                    'name': item.product.name,
                    'price': float(item.product.price),
                    'image': str(item.product.image.url) if item.product.image else None,
                },
                'variations': item_variations,
                'quantity': item.quantity,
            })
        total_price = sum(item.product.price * item.quantity for item in cart_items)
        logger.debug(f"Returning cart data: {cart_data}")
        return JsonResponse({'items': cart_data, 'subtotal': total_price})

    def update_quantity(self, request):
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            item_id = data.get('item_id')
            action = data.get('action')
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid JSON data'}, status=400)

        cart_item = get_object_or_404(Cart, id=item_id)

        if action == 'increase':
            cart_item.quantity += 1
        elif action == 'decrease':
            if cart_item.quantity > 1:
                cart_item.quantity -= 1

        cart_item.save()

        cart_items = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        cart_data = [
            {
                'id': item.id,
                'product': {
                    'id': item.product.id,
                    'name': item.product.name,
                    'price': float(item.product.price),
                    'image': item.product.image.url if item.product.image else None,
                },
                'variations': [v.product_variation.value for v in item.variations.all()],
                'quantity': item.quantity,
            }
            for item in cart_items
        ]
        total_price = sum(item.product.price * item.quantity for item in cart_items)

        return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'items': cart_data, 'subtotal': total_price})

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.path == '/cart/update_quantity/':
                return self.update_quantity(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                # Handle other POST requests here
                pass
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            if request.path == '/cart/data/':
                logger.debug(f"Request Path: {request.path}")
                return self.get_cart_data(request)
            else:
                # Handle other GET requests here
                pass

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

My urls.py:
path('login/', views.user_login_view, name='login'),

My settings.py:
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ''


Share the full urls

Hold on, you are doing an AJAX request?

why are you using  @method_decorator(login_required) decorator along with LoginRequiredMixin mixin?

Based on the fact that you work with JSON parsing and return a JSON blob (please don't do that), I assume that you make an AJAX request.
Now AJAX, as the name says, is Asynchronous, it makes these requests, and it even follows redirects to make queries, but the browser itself does not show the request and responses: JavaScript makes the request, sees the redirect, and makes another request. So the AJAX call ends up with the HTML content of the login view.
You thus will need to add logic to the AJAX handling, and if the user is not logged in, thus let the JavaScript redirect the browser to the login view. I would also advise to use the Django REST framework [drf-doc] or some other REST framework to handle REST APIs, since now you impelement a lot of boilerplate code. Furthermore prevent the user from visting a page where one can make an AJAX request that requires authentication: preemptively check this.

How can I do this without doing an AJAX request, because as you can tell JS is my weakness.
